# Rename "def" in python (and other keywords)

Tags: python

I am trying to write an 'interpretor' for a custom language.

The language is incredibly similar to python, but has some differences eg:

Python:

```
def subRoutine():
    print("hello")
```

Custom:

```
sub subRoutine()
    print("hello")
```

What would be the best way to solve this? 
Should i modify the python source and recompile, can i write a library that allows me to modify things at such a low level?

Cheers

Comment: Why are you doing this? A preprocessor for Python is not really a new "interpreter". Are you trying to learn something? Invent something truly new?

Comment: if you are trying to create a custom language, you might want to consider taking a look at Tcl. It allows you to redefine just about anything, and has a very simple syntax that is perfect for making custom DSLs.

Comment: http://mathamy.com/import-accio-bootstrapping-python-grammar.html have fun

Answer (score 6):

I would start by [this file](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/df395991f6341be037a5c6df9b14d924d5ac9e95/Grammar/Grammar), keeping in mind that:

> Changing the grammar specified in this file will most likely require corresponding changes in the parser module (../Modules/parsermodule.c).

At [line 27](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/df395991f6341be037a5c6df9b14d924d5ac9e95/Grammar/Grammar#L27):

```
funcdef: 'def' NAME parameters ['->' test] ':' suite
```

The grammar should however not change for a simple substitution of `def`, but the whole Python code of the stdlib will be heavily touched by the change.

---

I have tested it myself, using this source tarball, and replacing the `'def'` by `'createfunc'` in the `Grammar` file.
However, during CPython compilation, this error is raised:

```
Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: Unable to get the locale encoding
  File "/udd/lbourneu/Documents/projects/cpython/Python-3.4.4/Lib/encodings    /__init__.py", line 42
    def normalize_encoding(encoding):
                     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

You have to replace any `def` statement by the new one in order to get the python code compiling.

Note: using `find . -type f -name "*" -exec sed -i 's/def /createfunc /g' {} +` is not enough:

```
/usr/bin/mkdir -p Include
python3.4 ./Parser/asdl_c.py -h Include ./Parser/Python.asdl
  File "./Parser/asdl_c.py", line 14
    createfunc get_c_type(name):
                    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

---

The command `python3.4 ./Parser/asdl_c.py -h Include ./Parser/Python.asdl` and [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36478009/rename-def-in-python-and-other-keywords#comment60566952_36478009) show the problem: you need a python to compile python, and both needs to understand the same source code.
The trick introduced by the [linked article](http://mathamy.com/import-accio-bootstrapping-python-grammar.html) is to add a keyword instead of replace it.

Later, you can compile a third python that use the second one (which understand both `def` and `sub`) for compiling, with a grammar where the def keyword have been totally replaced by the new one.