# Can I change "import" (english) to "importar" (portuguese) in python?

Tags: python, built-in

To change a function in python I know I can simply assign to a new variable, like:

```
imprimir = print
imprimir("test") # it prints "test"
```

However I can't do that to `import`. Like `import = importar`.
I would like to do the following:

```
importar = import
como = as

importar pandas como pd
```

I know that many people think I should do this in English, but I'm writing an introductory paper that absolutely needs to be in my native language.

Any tips on how to achieve this?

Comment: No, import is a keyword.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Rename "def" in python (and other keywords)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36478009/rename-def-in-python-and-other-keywords), https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51992442/is-it-possible-to-redefine-keywords-in-python, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17489603/defining-aliases-for-keywords-in-python

Comment: Thanks, I was also wondering what type was "import". Now I got it. Keywords are not be messed around

Comment: You'd better explain in your paper that this is a bad idea rather than translating default method/keywords

Comment: You could write your own importer that translates the Portuguese keywords into the English keywords required by Python, but that's a fair bit of work, and then people would need the importer to run your code. And you'd still have to rename all the modules and methods...

Comment: I was wondering if it was possible. I know that is not advisable

Comment: Also, I don't speak Portuguese, but isn't that the infinitive form? you'd probably want to use the imperative form: "you, import!" rather than "to import."

Comment: That's a nice touch, @kindall... "importe pandas como pd" would be more appropriate if I were to use in portuguese

Comment: my high school Spanish classes prove their worth once again!

Answer (score 2):

`import` is a [Keyword](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#keywords) that is tokenized by the parser. Since this happens when parsing the .py source file, well before any code runs and any sort of assignment could happen, you are stuck.

Not completely. You could always grab the python source and change the parser. But, ouch. `import` is better.

There is an `__import__` function. You could use that instead of `import`, but you'd still have to call it like a function, not use it as a keyword.

```
importar = __import__
pd = importar("pandas")
```

This would be confusing to most python programmers who see your code later. And would also confuse any code analysis tool such as an IDE offering type hints.

Comment: That's very interesting, I didn't know it was possible

Comment: what about "if"? Could I translate it to "se" and that would even work?

Comment: Not completely, but you could write a function like `def se_nose(_truth_value, _if_true, _if_false)` Internally it would do `return _if_true() if _truth_value, else _if_false()` - now you have the right name, but the semantics are different.